# What is best way to update digital certificates from server to many clients when certificate expires?

Tags: authentication, digital-certificate

One of my friend is working on issue related to updating expired digital certificates.

He is working on Java application(Swings I guess), which has 4000 clients. All those need a digital certificate to connect to the application and this certificate expires every year.
At the end of year he needs to update the certificate credentials for all clients. Currently this is manual process, done by connecting to each of 4000 systems either locally or by remote connection.

He is got task to convert this process to be an automated process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the client-side certificate (used by authenticating the client on the server) needs to be passed to the client physically (on the carrier), otherwise, if the certificate is sent via electronic channels, there's a high risk of interception. But if secure connection is used, then the problem becomes less critical.

So the answer depends on how the client-side application is built. The easiest approach would be to add capabilities to refresh the certificate (*before* it expires) right from the application. The application would request fresh certificate from the server.

If no such capabilities are built-in and there's no way to add them, then the answer would depend on where the client-side application stores the certificate, used for authentication. If it's some file, then automating remote desktop connection using some automation tool would be the only choice.